# find pattern from log file using awk

Tags: awk

```
[QFJ Timer]:2014-07-02 06:19:09,030:bla.all.com.bla.bla.ppp.xxx.abcsedf:
```

i would like to extract the date and time.
so the date is no problem :

```
cat bla.log |awk -F: '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'
```

now the issue is with the time.
if i do : `cat bla.log |awk '{print $3}'` so i get:

```
06:19:09,030:bla.all.com.bla.bla.ppp.xxx.abcsedf:
```

which mean that i need another grep here right?

but i did so many tries using also 'FS' and didn't get only the time.

Can someone please advise?

Thank you.

Comment: what would be your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat bla.log |awk -F":" '{print $2":"$3":"$4}' | awk -F"," '{print $1}'
```

Which gets you:

```
2014-07-02 06:19:09
```

Comment: king! thank you very much.
but what if i want them in sepaeret outputs?

Comment: Put it through awk again | awk '{print $1,$2}' or use cut

Comment: This is not the best solution since it calls awk multiple times for no reason. The other solutions are better.

Comment: I agree, awk -vFS=":|," '{ print $2":"$3":"$4;}' is certainly more elegant.

Comment: Just hint: You are showing *useless use of `cat`*, and encouraging the OP to use two `awk` processes where one would be enough.

Comment: Thanks.
can you please tell me why if i add the NR option i got no putput?
awk  'NR==5 -F":" {print $2":"$3":"$4}'

Answer (score 2):

In the GNU version of awk FS can be a regexp:

```
echo "[QFJ Timer]:2014-07-02 06:19:09,030:bla.all.com.bla.bla.ppp.xxx.abcsedf:" |
awk -vFS=":|," '{ print $2":"$3":"$4;}'
```

which spits out

```
2014-07-02 06:19:09
```

Your left separator is ':' and the right is ',', and unfortunately hours, minutes and seconds are also separated by your left separator. That is solved by printing $3 and $4. Quick and dirty solution, but it isn't going to be be very robust.

Comment: You should output colons between hour/minute and minute/second. `print $2":"$3":"$4`

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed for this purpose,

```
$ echo '[QFJ Timer]:2014-07-02 06:19:09,030:bla.all.com.bla.bla.ppp.xxx.abcsedf:' | sed 's/^[^:]*:\([^,]*\).*/\1/g'
2014-07-02 06:19:09
```

Comment: Always nice to see a `sed` solution! Beginning anchor is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`, since it is meant for that:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}\(-[0-9]\{2\}\)\{2\}\(\( \|:\)[0-9]\{2\}\)\{3\}' log.file
```

or, a little bit simpler, `egrep`:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}(( |:)[0-9]{2}){3}' log.file
```